# I am trying to install scrapy using pip install Scrapy. but i am getting error as Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python

It also gives an error " failed building wheel for twisted". I already have higher version microsoft visual c++ 14.0.
i even tried installing twisted, but i get same error for installing Twisted.

[Error while running pip install Scrapy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRt98.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy documentation is recommending using Anaconda (or Miniconda) to install Scrapy on Windows ([link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows)):

> Though it’s possible to install Scrapy on Windows using pip, we recommend you to install Anaconda or Miniconda and use the package from the conda-forge channel, which will avoid most installation issues.

Anaconda is a Python software distribution with data science and machine learning in mind, whereas Miniconda is trimmed-down version of Anaconda with easy way to install additional packages. For your use case I recommend Miniconda.

If you don't want to use Miniconda, maybe let's focus on installing Twisted first. It has recommendations for installing on Windows ([link](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads#ThroughPip)):

> If you are installing on Windows, pip install Twisted[windows_platform] will install the Windows-specific requirements.

Maybe you could try installing Twisted first and then try to install Scrapy?

Comment: if I install Scrapy using Miniconda, will I be able to use Scrapy in Pycharm software

Comment: Yes, here's how to configure it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html